# Click event on table row is not getting bound in Angular 4

Tags: angular, onclick

I have below code in my component template in which click event is not getting bound. How can the click event be bound on the table row?

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of TabItems" [innerHTML]="item.Tab" (click)="displayTable(item)"></tr>
```

Comment: can we see displayTable() method of your component class?

Comment: the mehod looks like `displayTable(item:any){ //Code here }`

Comment: did you try to put a console.log inside displayTable to test it. cause i just tried your code and it works. [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vnzbi2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

ok, you can do it like this.

```
    <tr *ngFor="let item of TabItems" [innerHTML]="item.Tab" (click)="displayTable($event)"></tr>
    
    displayTable(event:any){
      let item = this.TabItems.find((a) => a.Tab === event.target.value) // this will give you the row which you have selected 
// you can change a.Tab to something else if you are getting other value from the event.target.value
    
    //your rest of the code here
    }
```